# Handlebars partial display name instead of template in loopback

Tags: handlebars.js, loopbackjs

I have a wired problem of partial showing the name instead of the template itself in loopback. For some reason the partials are not getting registered. Following is my code ... I am sure I am missing something but not able to quite figure it out. All help the appreciated. I am using express-handlebars as the bridge between loopback and handlebars

In server.js, I have the following code

```
var handlebars  = require('handlebars');
var exphbs      = require('express-handlebars');

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout : '',
    helpers       : {},
    extname       : 'handlebars'
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/../client/views');
```

Following is my express router code  ...

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.render('index', {
         partials: {
            mypartial : 'awesomepartial'
         },
     });
 });
```

... and the partial tag from index page. The partial page is just plain html code

```
{{> mypartial}}
```

.... when the index template gets executed, instead of seeing the text from awesomepartial.handlebars template (which resides in same directory as index.handlebars) I see following text

```
awesomepartial
```

What could I be doing wrong? Why is handlebars sending the partial name back instead of template code. I tried various combinations which makes me believe that path may not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Following is the working code ...

```
var handlebars  = require('handlebars');
var exphbs      = require('express-handlebars');

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout : '',
    helpers       : {},
    partialsDir   :  __dirname + '/../client/views',
    extname       : 'handlebars'
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/../client/views');


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index', {
       mypartial : 'awesomepartial'
   });
});

{{> (lookup . 'mypartial'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a dynamic partial which is done like so:

{{> (mypartial)}}

basically just wrapping the variable with parens. See docs for "Dynamic Partials" here: http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the pointer.

Your solution gave me "408 TypeError: Custom message: undefined is not a function", so ended up doing {{> (lookup . 'partials.mypartial') }} and defining partialsDir   : __dirname + '/../client/views', valiable while creating an instance of exphbs.